# custom error pages for IBM Domino iNotes

Tags: lotus-domino

we're currently customizing iNotes for a customer (platform currently is Domino 9). We almost reached our goals, but one thing that's on our todo list I can't really figure out: they want us to also customize any possible error pages; see the following example screenshot:
[image: iNotes error page]
This and other similar pages seem to come from the central Forms9.nsf which I'd love to leave as it is. We so far tried domcfg.nsf mappings, but as this is an iNotes internal error it obviously can't work; I also tried to figure out a way to put seomething into our customized Forms9_x.nsf but without any hint this is too abstract for me.

So my questions are:

- has anyone ever done this?
- what options do we have (apart from "hacking" Forms9.nsf)?

Many thanks in advance...

*Update:*
After continuing to play with domcfg mappings I suddenly saw a first result; not sure what's the difference to the first attempts, though; maybe moving the error form to Forms9_x.nsf did the trick? I'll keep investigating and post an answer if I can find one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this has been an afternoon of wild guessing and hacking along, but finally I think I found it:

first of all, my playing around with domcfg mappings didn't have to do with solving the problem; instead, I just by chance had put my error page form into my Forms9_x.nsf and named it `$$ReturnGeneralError` (that's simply the name used in Forms9.nsf...; I completely had forgotton about those 4 pre-defined form names back from Domino 5 times).

What **did not work** was the old method of simply including a text file named `MessageString` to display the exact error message returned from the server; obviously iNotes is handling those error strings differently.

After a few hours of testing, and comparing codes between the standard iNotes error page and mine I finally found it: include some iNotes specific computed text into the page, in my case that is

@{{MessageString}; html}

See [this](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/The_basics_of_iNotes_customization#Special+Server-side+tags) document for some details (last row in the table)

Hopefully this can help someone else as well...